# Parsing Rasa NLU from multiple models

Tags: python, rasa-nlu

I am looking for parsing trained project with multiple models other than only the last model in the project.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:5000/parse -d '{"q":"hello there", "project":"my_restaurant_search_bot"}'
```

Please refer to https://nlu.rasa.com/http.html

I am trying this only because of my huge intents taking a large amount of time on a single file training in MITIE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your old version you should be able do a request like this (documented [here](https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/nlu/http/#post-parse)):

```
curl -XPOST localhost:5000/parse -d '{"q":"hello there", "project": "my_restaurant_search_bot", "model": "<model_XXXXXX>"}'
```